# Could not find module FindOpenCV.cmake in ROS Build

Tags: opencv, ros, opencv3.0

when i want build my package in ros this error show my:

```
CMake Error at image_view/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" (requested
  version 3.4.9) with any of the following names:
    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake




  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/beny/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/beny/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:2490: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you currently have version 3.4.9 of OpenCV installed?

Comment: Yes, I have version 3.4.9 installed